# Random number generator within loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, nested

trying to create a Random number generator within a while loop that controls the Number Guessing Game. The issue is the "too high" and "too low" hints will say one number (ex:35) is too low, but then say the nest input number (ex:36) is too high. Then when I move the call a random function in the nested while loop, it generates the same random number each time.

I have tried moving the call to random function to my most inner loop, but then it generates the same random number. Currently, it is in the outer while loop, but then the issue of the high/lows occurs

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class numberGuessingGame
{
     public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        int randomNumber, userNumber = 0, guesses = 0, correct;
        final int MAX = 100;
        char playAgain, playGame = 'y'; 


        //ask user if they wish to play   
        System.out.println("Would you like to play the Number          Guessing Game? y / n");

        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        playGame = scan.next().charAt(0); 
        Random generator = new Random();

        //while loop to continue to exacute game as long as user enters 'y'
        while (playGame == 'y'){
            if (playGame != 'y') 
               break;

            randomNumber = generator.nextInt(MAX) + 1;
            //flag
            correct = 0;

           //loop to control the round
           while (correct == 0) {

                //get user number

                System.out.println("Please pick a number between 1 and 100.");
                userNumber = scan.nextInt();

               //high and low sugguestion
                if (userNumber > randomNumber)
                    System.out.println("Number is too high, try     something lower.");

                if (userNumber < randomNumber)
                    System.out.println("Number is too low, try something higher.");

                if (userNumber == randomNumber){ 
                 System.out.println("That number is correct!");
                    System.out.println("Would you like to play again? y/n");
                    playGame = scan.next().charAt(0);
                }

                guesses++;
                System.out.println("You have guessed " + guesses + " times!");
           }  

    }
        //break statement skips here when 'n' is entered in
        // the game prompting question
        System.out.println("Thanks for playing, have a nice day!");  
 }
```

}

Comment: so, when do you update the `correct` flag? Otherwise the inner `while` loop will never terminate, right? Hint: it should be when the user guesses the correct number.

Comment: And asking for a new game should happen **after** the inner `while` loop, not inside it. It won't change anything in the workflow right now, but is semantically more "accurate"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to suggest some changes you might consider:

- use a `boolean` for `correct` rather than an `int`
- remove your `if` statement immediately after the `while`: it is redundant
- use `do-while` when the loop must be executed at least once
- use `Integer.compareTo` rather than separate comparisons

Answer (score 0):

> Your inner loop does not terminate that's why you have the same
>   randomNumber, change `correct=0` value to terminate the inner while loop

```
if (userNumber == randomNumber){ 
 System.out.println("That number is correct!");
 System.out.println("Would you like to play again? y/n");
 playGame = scan.next().charAt(0);
 correct=1; //Just to remove correct=0 value
}
```